# How does one usually compute the gradient and the Hessian of a proposal in a MCMC algorithm?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

In some proposals of a MCMC, the mean/location vector and the covariance/scale matrix are functions of the gradient/jacobian and hessian of the log-likelihood.

I'm wondering how does one usually find the gradient and hessian for complex models?
Is it by a numerical routine/procedure? Which one?

Or do they simply use a BFGS type of algorithm to find the maximisers of the log-likelihood?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you’d normally find it by optimization. An example off the top of my head is Baumeister and Hamilton who, in their 2015 Econometrica paper “Sign Restrictions, Structural Vector Autoregressions, and Useful Prior Information”, simply use the fminunc function in Matlab with default optimizer.

Comment: In that paper, they know the general form(for a sample size $n$) of the function, and then use that minimization algorithm right? If we can't know the general form of the function for a sample size, than that procedure may became too computationally burdensome, right?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea They get the hessian numerically. I’m not sure which function you’re referring to (“they know the general form of the function”). They know the likelihood and prior, the product of which they maximize.

Comment: I'm going to check the paper. It may take a while until I accept your answer. In 2 weeks, if I haven't said anything, feel free to write a comment here. ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea I think they just mention it in passing in the paper. But Baumeiser has made code available here which may be more illuminating: https://sites.google.com/site/cjsbaumeister/research

Answer (score 0):

I would think in most of those cases, the assumption is, that the gradients and Hessians are coming from symbolic calculations (or autodiff), as computing the Hessian (even ignoring issues of numerical precision) requires ~ $N^2$ calculations where N is the dimensionality of the problem.